# Convert actionscript float to java

Tags: java, actionscript-3, hex

I need to convert this actionscript code to java:

```
p = 0xe8af7c;    
var ba: ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.writeFloat ((p >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255);
ba.writeFloat ((p >> 8 & 0xFF) / 255);
ba.writeFloat ((p & 0xFF) / 255);
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
int p = 0xe8af7c;
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output));
dos.writeFloat ((p >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255f);
dos.writeFloat ((pix >> 8 & 0xFF) / 255f);
dos.writeFloat ((pix & 0xFF) / 255f);
```

But this does not produce the same results. It should produce `3f 68 e8 e9 3f 2f af b0 3e f8 f8 f9`, but it returns `3f 68 d7 98 d7 99 3f 2f c2 af c2 b0 3e d7 a8 d7 a8 d7 a9`. Does it mean actionscript handles floats different than java and this function cannot be converted like this? How should I convert this code?

**EDIT:** The purpose of this is to get the three digit pairs of p - e8, af, and 7c, convert them to integers, which are 232, 175, 124, then divide those values by 255, and write to DataOutputStream them.

Comment: That seems like a lot of bytes for a `Float`. Are you putting other things in there? Please post a minimal, complete, and reproducible example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I edited my question, I had forgotten to add two more lines.

Comment: Apparently `java.io.FileOutputStream(output)` converts received bytes into UTF8 characters, that would explain changing `e8` into `d7 98` and `e9` into `d7 99`. So, you've hit a text conversion issue with `output` which is a text file by default.

Answer (score 2):

Using this code

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int p = 0xe8af7c;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(12);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    dos.writeFloat((p >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255f);
    dos.writeFloat((p >> 8 & 0xFF) / 255f);
    dos.writeFloat((p & 0xFF) / 255f);
    System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(bos.toByteArray()));
}
```

I get the following output:

```
3f68e8e93f2fafb03ef8f8f9
```

which matches your desired result

```
3f 68 e8 e9 3f 2f af b0 3e f8 f8 f9
```

So you're probably writing something extra to your `output` that you aren't showing us here.

Also take a look at `ByteBuffer` for an fancy byte array with conversion methods.

Comment: I'm not getting this output in my hex editor. In the actionscript program's output It shows like this `?hèé?/¯°>øøù` in the ansi panel and the output you gave in the hex pane. But your program outputs the hex values in the ansi pane. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Never mind, the output actually for some weird reason was correct all this time. I'm writing to a file which I open in the hex editor.

Comment: @Cobold Why writing binary data into a text receiver? You've got your data mangled by charset conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing data correctly into `DataOutputStream`, but it gets damaged when you pipe it into `output` because the data has to go to console, and your bytes are interpreted as ANSI chars and get "corrected" into UTF-8 charset, resulting in two bytes being sent to the console, which you in turn capture via OS pipeline into a file. To fix, use a `FileOutputStream` with a normal file as destination instead of `output`.